# song ratings on iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, ratings

I used to be able to rate a song one star to 5 stars while listening to it on my iPhone.  I do not have that option any more.  Now, when I tap on the title of the song, it only takes me to the album, and I can only "heart" it or not.

I have figured out how to get my ratings back in iTunes..

How do I view and edit the rating for a song on my iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than tapping the title of the song, tap the album cover while the song is playing. There, the five dots to rate the song will appear.